# How to combine two tables

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

This must be super easy, though I can't figure it out. I have these two tables:

```
examplea = 
 Table[{a, i, attrib1, attrib2, RandomInteger[10000]}, {i, 1, 3}] // 
  TableForm

a   1   attrib1 attrib2 3061

a   2   attrib1 attrib2 8818

a   3   attrib1 attrib2 3762

exampleb = 
 Table[{b, i, attrib1, attrib2, RandomInteger[10000]}, {i, 21, 23}] //
   TableForm

b   21  attrib1 attrib2 1480

b   22  attrib1 attrib2 857

b   23  attrib1 attrib2 347
```

And I now need to make one list looking like this:

```
a   1   attrib1 attrib2 3061

a   2   attrib1 attrib2 8818

a   3   attrib1 attrib2 3762

b   21  attrib1 attrib2 1480

b   22  attrib1 attrib2 857

b   23  attrib1 attrib2 347
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that you are setting the tables to your variables already in tableform, which makes them more awkward to use.

You can either set the non-tableform tables and *then* display in tableform ...

```
Print@TableForm[examplea = Table[{a, i, attrib1, attrib2,
      RandomInteger[10000]}, {i, 1, 3}]];

Print@TableForm[exampleb = Table[{b, i, attrib1, attrib2,
      RandomInteger[10000]}, {i, 21, 23}]];

Join[examplea, exampleb] // TableForm
```

... Or you have to extract the tables from tableform to join them :-

```
Print[examplea = Table[{a, i, attrib1, attrib2,
      RandomInteger[10000]}, {i, 1, 3}] // TableForm];

Print[exampleb = Table[{b, i, attrib1, attrib2,
      RandomInteger[10000]}, {i, 21, 23}] // TableForm];

Join[First@examplea, First@exampleb] // TableForm
```